# alarmmanager selected time and date

Tags: android

Using this code, I try to set alarmmanager to stars Notify.class at 25/12/2012 - 15.15 but when I use this code no Notify.class starts. Where's the problem?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());

    cal.set(Calendar.DATE,25); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);     
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);     

Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, Notify.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,intent3, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="Notify"></activity>
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.AlarmReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: is Notify.class registered in your manifest?  Do you have a broadcast receiver registered to receive the broadcast?  Is Notify.class an activity (use PendingIntent.getActivity), a service  (use PendingIntent.getService), a broadcast receiver (use PendingIntent.getBroadcast)?  You can read more about pending intent here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: Yes, I already checked the manifest and everything is ok.

Comment: Ok, can you show us your manifest and Notify.class then?

Comment: If you take the intent filter out does it work? Also note that you're modifying the calendar, so it will not execute ASAP, it will execute on the 25th, set a time in the very near future to actually get the Alarm to execute

Comment: @A--C Perhaps he is modifying the date on his phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write this

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="AlarmReceiver"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You have switched **android:name** for receiver and it's intent filter. You may replace **com.example.AlarmReceiver** with **.AlarmReceiver**

after you have made this change in your manifest, whatever code you have written inside onReceive() method of your broadcast receiver **com.example.AlarmReceiver** will get executed.

What your code will do is it will set alarm manager for the specified date-time. At that moment it will fire an intent with action name **AlarmReceiver**. Your Broadcast receiver is in Manifest so it will catch the broadcast and execute it's onReceive() Method.

If you want to start an activity write context.startActivity(...) inside onReceive().

**Edit:** also change your intent to this:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent("AlarmReceiver");
```

Comment: To be on the safe side, he should change his intent to `Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);` Using strings in Intent constructors is asking for things to not work.

Comment: Oh Yes Ofcourse. but isn't naming intents supposed to be a good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to start the Activity Notify.class, then just change this line:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast
```

to

```
PendingIntent.getActivity
```

Also you should change this line in your manifest:

from:

```
<activity android:name="Notify"></activity>
```

to

```
<activity android:name=".Notify"></activity>
```

You should also provide a android:name and android:label for this activity.

If you are trying to use getBroadcast instead, you need to change this line so your receiver gets the broadcast instead of starting an activity with the pending intent.  For that you would use

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

Instead of

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, Notify.class);
```

You would also want to add an action to your intent3, example:

intent3.setAction("com.example.AlarmReceiver");

That way in your AlarmReceiver you can filter for that intent and perform an action, such as launching an activity Notify.class, using a new intent.